# WPF: Using dispatcher to move caret in TextBox VS. not using it

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a TextBox in which I want to move the caret based on the GotFocus and LostFocus events. On GotFocus I have to use the dispatcher to move it and without it, the move doesn't happen. On LostFocus I tried using the dispatcher too, but when I used it the caret didn't move. I moved the caret index without the dispatcher and the move happened.

I would like to know what is the difference between these two methods and in what situations should I use them?

XAML of TextBox:

```
<TextBox Margin="75,25,30,0" LostFocus="MoveCarretToStart" GotFocus="MoveCarretToEnd" Background="Transparent"   MaxLength="100" Height="25" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Name="LabelFreeText" Width="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="12" FontStyle="Italic">
```

Methods in code behind:

```
 private void MoveCarretToEnd(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() =>
        {                
            LabelFreeText.CaretIndex = LabelFreeText.Text.Length;
        }));
    }

    private void MoveCarretToStart(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LabelFreeText.CaretIndex = 0;          
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `GotFocus` and `LostFocus` events work fine either way (with or without invoke). However, if `GotFocus` is fired after a mouse event (rather than a keyboard event) the caret will move automatically to the position of the mouse. And because `MouseDown` event is handled after `GotFocus` **the caret index will be overwritten by the next event**.

You can disable this automatic behaviour using `PreviewMouseDown`:

```
    private void LabelFreeText_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        LabelFreeText.Focus();//select the control
        e.Handled = true;//don't move the caret anymore
    }
    private void MoveCarretToEnd(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LabelFreeText.CaretIndex = LabelFreeText.Text.Length;
    }
```

The reason why `BeginInvoke` made it work is because of the [Event Loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop). What you did basically was to postpone the moving of the caret to the end of the event queue so that the last thing to be processed is the change of CaretIndex :

```
private void MoveCarretToEnd(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() =>
        //wait until current event queue is handled
    {
        LabelFreeText.CaretIndex = LabelFreeText.Text.Length;
    }));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Read about [wpf threading model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/threading-model):

> WPF applications start with two threads: one for handling rendering and another for managing the UI

WPF uses routed events, while event may signalize about something, it may not necessarily already rendered, rather queued. I am not sure if event handlers are also queued, but this doesn't matter for a conclusion: sometimes you will need to *synchronize* actions in event handler with rendering queue (or even postpone it by specifying correct priority).

[LostFocus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.lostfocus(v=vs.110).aspx)/[GotFocus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.gotfocus(v=vs.110).aspx) are not *direct events* (see [routing strategies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/routed-events-overview#routing-strategies)) and it looks like for `GotFocus` you need this synchronization, control is either also set caret, overriding value you set in event handler, or ignoring your call due to some invalid state.

For those coming from winforms there is a rule of thumbs: if something obvious is not working in wpf event handler - try it with invoke.